# react native render a element outside the component boundary

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render a button outside of the component's boundary. How can I do that? I have the styles looks like as shown below. The negative position works but the button get hidden by a sibling component. In the below image, the blue color is a sibling component. You can see the round button positioned in negative is hidden by the sibling component. Why? how can make it visible? I tried zIndex, but looks like it works only within the same component.

If the above question is not clear, let's say A, B, C are three components. A is the parent and, B and C are child components. I want to render a button from B and it must overlay on top of B. I don't want to render the button from component A. Any help appreciated.

[image]

```
Btn: {
position: 'absolute',
zIndex: 1000000,
width: 50,
height: 50,
top: -27,
left: 20,
backgroundColor: 'red'
},
```

Comment: Looks like you have misspelt `z-index: 1000;`. Does this fix it?

Comment: no, in react native, you have use zIndex. z-index won't work in react native.

Comment: Ahh, sorry misread it was using react

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you solve this?

Comment: i'm having the same problem ,can you help me if you slove it?

Answer (score 0):

The part where you render button, place that on the bottommost part of the render function where you are rendering the button and the siblings. Then with the absolute positioning, it would bet render last, and hence at the top. You wouldn't need z-index in this case. I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: No, in that case, the button needs to be part render method of the parent component which renders the siblings. I want the button to be part of one of the siblings (child components of the parent).  A, B, C are three components. A is the parent and, B and C are child components. I want to render a button from B and it must overlay on top of B. I don't want to render the button from component A.

Answer (score 0):

If it's android app use `elevation` property instead of `z-index` on B component